# REST WS Spring MVC Payload XSD validation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, saxparser

I have implemented POST REST WS by using Spring MVC.

I'm struggled at the moment on a XML payload validation issue.

I've defined a complex type object in a XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyObject">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="dedicatedType" type="tns:MyType" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="MyType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="TYPE_ONE" />
        <xs:enumeration value="TYPE_TWO" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This XSD is afterwards converted to Java classes using JAXB. 
The corresponding generated Java class is refered from the request params in the controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/mydomain/createMyObject", 
    headers = "Accept=*/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response createMyObject(
        @Valid @RequestBody final MyObject myObject, 
        final HttpServletRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

As seen from the XSD definition, this object contains a property that is of an enum type 'MyType'. When submitting the POST request with the XML payload, I would like to get a validation on the content of it but whatever the content is for the enum, I don't get any validation error and a null value is assigned to the ad-hoc enum. I would like to be able to get a validation error in order to inform the client that there was a validation error in the XML payload provided.

Would anyone have any suggestion on how to force a content validation on the enum to ensure the value is corresponding to one of the defined enum values?

Many thanks in advance.

Seb.

(Spring version in use is 3.0.6)